# Why does subreport not split?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using iReport 4.7.1, I have a main report with 2 subreport's (one in the header band, the other one in the detail band).

The second subreport is longer than the first page, so I would like to split it in order to have a part of the text in the next page. 
I set:

- every band splitType = "stretch";
- all sub report components need Position Type=Fix Relative to Top;
- every components of the subreport Stretch Type=No stretch;
- all sub reports Ignore pagination=false;

The problem is that the subreport is always printed in the next page, where all the report can fill the entire page.
I tried also many other combination of these property without success.

**Main report:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ConsensoLR" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="750" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="9" rightMargin="20" topMargin="14" bottomMargin="14" uuid="8be2069c-89a5-4e39-942c-f679c2f3a6ba">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.75"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <group name="PATENTE" minHeightToStartNewPage="500">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[null]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
                <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="03d42b27-b701-48d0-97a4-544d270e9009" key="subreport-1" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="8" y="0" width="556" height="17" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["../../forms/Consensi/HeaderConsensiCardiologia.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="PATENTE1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[null]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f0cc7497-4bcb-4acb-971b-89a08054b5fc" key="subreport-1" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="7" y="0" width="559" height="17" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["../../forms/Consensi/LR_Info.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="LR_Info" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="750" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="5851263f-4063-4a4e-b915-ce1fac591369">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="187"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="PAT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="PAT_PRENAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TxtClinicalSit" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ChxLanguageIt" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ChxLanguageOth" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ChxNationalityIt" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ChxNationalityOth" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TxtNationalityOth" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TxtLanguageOth" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TxtDoctor" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TxtSpiegazione" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="701" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="d9b4b7c5-b542-4691-8517-0e2ce00cddae" key="textField" x="113" y="10" width="130" height="19" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{PAT_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="5b827833-697c-4c7e-9e2b-5c318013b4f2" key="textField" x="247" y="10" width="128" height="19" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{PAT_PRENAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="2b1db4d3-c8d9-4880-a5c6-7515ea4f4bc6" key="staticText-25" x="9" y="10" width="100" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Io sottoscritto/a]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="4822a8bc-9f02-4d5c-a1d6-2aec989cbd71" key="staticText-26" x="381" y="10" width="62" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nazionalià]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="93d5deb1-d7db-4654-943b-57305132cfaa" key="staticText-27" x="9" y="33" width="89" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Lingua parlata]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5a97151a-5a41-426a-b513-2de3dfe4c3ed" key="staticText-28" x="247" y="33" width="305" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[dichiaro di essere stato/a informato/a in modo ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="300703d9-eda6-432a-9404-c2d6df82ac4b" key="staticText-29" x="9" y="56" width="543" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["comprensibile ed adeguato dal Dott." + $P{TxtDoctor} + " e di avere letto e compreso"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="fb8b979b-cb1a-4279-9392-cf71b07fbc91" key="staticText-30" x="9" y="79" width="543" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[le informazioni scritte relative a:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1dfe9127-4ee7-4dd5-be63-4584de0ba11a" key="staticText-31" x="9" y="102" width="152" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[- la mia situazione attuale:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="413ad418-7549-4318-acd7-bfcf333244e9" key="staticText-32" x="9" y="124" width="540" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[- il trattamento cardiologico consigliato per la guarigione o per migliorare la prognosi:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="89259a96-d0e4-4884-9202-644054a7aeed" key="staticText-33" x="9" y="144" width="534" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true" isUnderline="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[IMPIANTO DI LOOP RECORDER SOTTOCUTANEO:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="93bc1c0a-92b1-4b74-a584-399a9c7050a1" key="staticText-34" x="9" y="158" width="537" height="86" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[la procedura, effettuata in anestesia locale previa somministrazione di un blando sedativo, prevede il confezionamento di una piccola tasca sottocutanea in regione pettorale, dove viene posizionato il dispositivo. Nella fase successiva si procede alla sutura della ferita. Durante l’intervento vengono costantemente monitorate le funzioni vitali (frequenza cardiaca, pressione arteriosa) ed è presente il personale medico ed infermieristico in grado di affrontare ogni situazione di urgenza o emergenza clinica.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b77f20ec-48c7-40bc-af49-96765f3e6903" key="staticText-37" x="9" y="244" width="540" height="24" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[•    le alternative diagnostiche, a sostanziale parità di efficacia, e le ragioni che motivano l’intervento:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="538d282d-3adc-4bf9-aa16-ee389e529bf1" key="staticText-38" x="9" y="305" width="536" height="15"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[•    le eventuali terapie da effettuare / sospendere prima dell’intervento consigliato: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d5db8114-d2f2-4fb8-b13a-13b232aed45b" key="staticText-39" x="17" y="268" width="527" height="29" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[non esistono alternative diagnostiche in grado di monitorizzare il ritmo cardiaco per tempi prolungati ed in modo continuativo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c7e1d76f-2a0c-41ff-b00a-a1d431bad85e" key="staticText-40" x="18" y="319" width="526" height="39"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[▪    profilassi antibiotica per la prevenzione delle infezioni intraoperatorie
▪   sospensione terapia anticoagulante per os e antiaggregante per ridurre il rischio di sanguinamento (salvo controindicazioni cliniche).]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f5b92285-b9e7-4a72-abd9-c1d8f7c1b0ff" key="staticText-41" x="9" y="369" width="536" height="37"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[<style isBold="true">•   i benefici attesi dall’intervento consigliato:</style> il dispositivo permette una registrazione continua del ritmo cardiaco e permette di diagnosticare o di escludere eventuali turbe del ritmo che potrebbero essere alla base degli episodi di perdita di coscienza da me accusati.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="593a3df1-9ab7-487e-b7dd-153061602b4d" key="staticText-41" x="10" y="418" width="536" height="24" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[<style isBold="true">•   i disagi correlati all’intervento:</style> dovrò rimanere a letto nelle 12 ore successive all’intervento.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="8106c5f9-ae6b-4252-87a3-9fe11e456002" key="textField-26" x="172" y="101" width="377" height="19"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{TxtClinicalSit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="48fa1de0-8e26-4edd-b5d6-bb5075da4e49" key="textField" mode="Transparent" x="454" y="10" width="98" height="19">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean ($P{ChxNationalityIt}.equals("true"))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Italiana"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="2a290db1-3278-4285-a0e2-84552b111df0" key="textField" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="454" y="10" width="98" height="19">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean ($P{ChxNationalityOth}.equals("true"))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{TxtNationalityOth}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="af9b0a17-0eb2-47ea-aa66-49e4b2252f37" key="textField" mode="Transparent" x="113" y="33" width="130" height="19">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean ($P{ChxLanguageOth}.equals("true"))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{TxtLanguageOth}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="3339fbe6-5aa4-4516-a86d-3dfc15565bb8" key="textField" mode="Transparent" x="113" y="33" width="130" height="19">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean ($P{ChxLanguageIt}.equals("true"))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="11" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Italiana"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b9d31cde-d14e-4ed6-9635-80feb00e4595" key="staticText-41" x="8" y="451" width="536" height="49" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[<style isBold="true">•   i possibili rischi e complicanze connessi all’intervento consigliato</style>: alla procedura sono connesse alcune possibili complicanze:
▪ Ematomi superficiali o in sede di tasca (1% dei casi) correlati al possibile sanguinamento della ferita
▪ Infezione della tasca (0,2% dei casi)
]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="7ebbff68-5f7d-48be-9b53-c4191a7f1e87" key="staticText-41" x="8" y="512" width="536" height="50"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[<style isBold="true">•   la possibilità di dover modificare o ampliare l’intervento, così come già programmato e autorizzato, di fronte a situazioni impreviste e al momento difficilmente prevedibili</style>:
come sede dell’impianto viene generalmente scelta la regione pettorale sinistra, ma in casi particolari (precedenti interventi chirurgici…) tale sede potrà essere elettivamente la destra.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b50f5f5b-5e2c-4992-b43c-d7842b890472" key="staticText-41" x="10" y="567" width="536" height="28"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[<style isBold="true">•   le prevedibili conseguenze della “non cura”</style>: la scelta di non sottopormi all’intervento implica la mancata diagnosi delle possibili cause aritmiche alla base dei sintomi da me accusati.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="400b521d-53b9-4b1f-8513-ce8aecb3b28a" key="staticText-41" x="10" y="606" width="536" height="15"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
```

Comment: I found a possible solution. I create multiple details bands, the first one, was too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that that the detail band in subreport has **height="701"**, this means that it will start on first page that has this space available.

Honestly I can not understand why you use these subreport with empty datasource, trying to get fixed page layout (they have sense if you have a sub datasource).

You should probably revert back to only use main report where you can create a fixed page layout using title band, detail band, summary band and group bands.

Comment: Thank you, we tend to use subreport in order to re-use them in different reports. Anyway I tried your suggestion and I had the same problem. Shoul I post the text in the detail band or in a group header?

Comment: Try setting splitType="Immediate" for the subreport detail band.